# Proper manipulation of wide char/string in C

Tags: c, xcode, io, widechar, widestring

OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
XCode 7.2

I've been reading and experimenting whole day long, about wide char/string in C and I still can't make it work.

I'm trying to read a file composed only by wide characters like the followings:

```
んわらやま    (Japanese)
```

I want to read only one character at time, to write immediately inside the other file.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE    *source, *dest;

    source = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    if (source == NULL) {
        printf ("could not open source file \n");
        exit (1);
    }

//  if [dest] does not exist it is created
    dest = fopen( argv[2], "w+");
    if (dest == NULL) {
        fclose(source);
    
        printf ("could not open dest file \n");
        exit (1);
    }
    fwide(source, 1);
    fwide(dest, 1);

    fileManipulator(source, dest);

    fclose(source);
    fclose(dest);

    return 0;
    }

void fileManipulator(FILE* source, FILE* dest)
{
    wint_t token;

    while ( WEOF != (token = getwc(source))) {
        manipulateToken(token, dest);
    }
}


void manipulateToken(wint_t token, FILE* dest)
{
    char* pre = "- ";
    char* post= " -\n";

    if ( EOF == fputs(pre, dest))
    {
//      error handling
    }
    if ( WEOF == fputwc(token, dest))
    {
//      error handling
    }
    if ( EOF == fputs(post, dest))
    {
//      error handling
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
- „ -
- Ç -
- ì -
- „ -
- Ç -
- è -
- „ -
- Ç -
- â -
- „ -
- Ç -
- Ñ -
- „ -
- Å -
- æ -
```

I can understand that my problem probably is about how I read the data but If I think about alternatives I'm totally stuck.

- I've tried using **fgetws** but I'm not able to separate characters one from another;
- I've tried using **fwscanf** with *%ls* but I just ended up with an empty file;
- I noticed that MAC OS doesn't provide **fgetwc** implementation even if the relative man page mentions it, AFAIK **getwc** should be a macro implementation for **fgetwc**;
- Not sure if this is important but I created source file using **touch** command;

can you help me?

PS: Links to further readings on the argument are much appreciated as well. Documentation on the matter is pretty scarce.

---

## The XCode issue

This issue initially made me think that *Jonathan Leffler* solution was not working. In fact code produces different output if I run it through XCode <kbd>CMD+R</kbd> or through the **Terminal**.

AFAIK the issue must be some kind of attribute/property/setting XCode uses at run time, since hard-coding ***source*** and ***dest*** parameters still produces the wrong output.

For the sake of clarity I'm providing the exported scheme for my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Scheme
   LastUpgradeVersion = "0720"
   version = "1.3">
   <BuildAction
      parallelizeBuildables = "YES"
      buildImplicitDependencies = "YES">
      <BuildActionEntries>
         <BuildActionEntry
            buildForTesting = "YES"
            buildForRunning = "YES"
            buildForProfiling = "YES"
            buildForArchiving = "YES"
            buildForAnalyzing = "YES">
            <BuildableReference
               BuildableIdentifier = "primary"
               BlueprintIdentifier = "DA36663A1CCF4F8200615958"
               BuildableName = "FileManipulator"
               BlueprintName = "FileManipulator"
               ReferencedContainer = "container:FileManipulator.xcodeproj">
            </BuildableReference>
         </BuildActionEntry>
      </BuildActionEntries>
   </BuildAction>
   <TestAction
      buildConfiguration = "Debug"
      selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB"
      selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Launcher.LLDB"
      shouldUseLaunchSchemeArgsEnv = "YES">
      <Testables>
      </Testables>
      <MacroExpansion>
         <BuildableReference
            BuildableIdentifier = "primary"
            BlueprintIdentifier = "DA36663A1CCF4F8200615958"
            BuildableName = "FileManipulator"
            BlueprintName = "FileManipulator"
            ReferencedContainer = "container:FileManipulator.xcodeproj">
         </BuildableReference>
      </MacroExpansion>
      <AdditionalOptions>
      </AdditionalOptions>
   </TestAction>
   <LaunchAction
      buildConfiguration = "Debug"
      selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB"
      selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Launcher.LLDB"
      launchStyle = "0"
      useCustomWorkingDirectory = "NO"
      ignoresPersistentStateOnLaunch = "NO"
      debugDocumentVersioning = "YES"
      enableAddressSanitizer = "YES"
      debugServiceExtension = "internal"
      allowLocationSimulation = "YES">
      <BuildableProductRunnable
         runnableDebuggingMode = "0">
         <BuildableReference
            BuildableIdentifier = "primary"
            BlueprintIdentifier = "DA36663A1CCF4F8200615958"
            BuildableName = "FileManipulator"
            BlueprintName = "FileManipulator"
            ReferencedContainer = "container:FileManipulator.xcodeproj">
         </BuildableReference>
      </BuildableProductRunnable>
      <CommandLineArguments>
         <CommandLineArgument
            argument = "/Users/Paul/TestDirectory/Source.txt"
            isEnabled = "YES">
         </CommandLineArgument>
         <CommandLineArgument
            argument = "/Users/Paul/TestDirectory/Destination.txt"
            isEnabled = "YES">
         </CommandLineArgument>
      </CommandLineArguments>
      <AdditionalOptions>
         <AdditionalOption
            key = "NSZombieEnabled"
            value = "YES"
            isEnabled = "YES">
         </AdditionalOption>
         <AdditionalOption
            key = "NSDOLoggingEnabled"
            value = "YES"
            isEnabled = "YES">
         </AdditionalOption>
      </AdditionalOptions>
   </LaunchAction>
   <ProfileAction
      buildConfiguration = "Release"
      shouldUseLaunchSchemeArgsEnv = "YES"
      savedToolIdentifier = ""
      useCustomWorkingDirectory = "NO"
      debugDocumentVersioning = "YES">
      <BuildableProductRunnable
         runnableDebuggingMode = "0">
         <BuildableReference
            BuildableIdentifier = "primary"
            BlueprintIdentifier = "DA36663A1CCF4F8200615958"
            BuildableName = "FileManipulator"
            BlueprintName = "FileManipulator"
            ReferencedContainer = "container:FileManipulator.xcodeproj">
         </BuildableReference>
      </BuildableProductRunnable>
   </ProfileAction>
   <AnalyzeAction
      buildConfiguration = "Debug">
   </AnalyzeAction>
   <ArchiveAction
      buildConfiguration = "Release"
      revealArchiveInOrganizer = "YES">
   </ArchiveAction>
</Scheme>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to work.  You probably shouldn't be using `fputs()` and narrow strings; you should be using `fputws()` and wide strings: `L"- "`. Note the use of `setlocale()`; that is crucial (try omitting it and see what you get).

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

static void fileManipulator(FILE *source, FILE *dest);
static void manipulateToken(wint_t token, FILE *dest);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    FILE    *source, *dest;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input output\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    source = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (source == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open source file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    dest = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
    if (dest == NULL)
    {
        fclose(source);
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open dest file %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fwide(source, 1);
    fwide(dest, 1);

    fileManipulator(source, dest);

    fclose(source);
    fclose(dest);

    return 0;
}

static void fileManipulator(FILE *source, FILE *dest)
{
    wint_t token;

    while (WEOF != (token = getwc(source)))
    {
        manipulateToken(token, dest);
    }
}

static void manipulateToken(wint_t token, FILE *dest)
{
    wchar_t *pre = L"- ";
    wchar_t *post = L" -\n";

    if (EOF == fputws(pre, dest))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write prefix string\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (WEOF == fputwc(token, dest))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write wide character %d\n", (int)token);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (EOF == fputws(post, dest))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write suffix string\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Given a file, `data`, containing:

```
$ cat data
んわらやま
$ odx data
0x0000: E3 82 93 E3 82 8F E3 82 89 E3 82 84 E3 81 BE 0A   ................
0x0010:
$
```

(You won't have `odx` because I wrote it, but `xxd -g 1 data` produces more or less equivalent output.)  I ran the program (called `x37`) like this:

```
$ x37 data output
$ cat output
- ん -
- わ -
- ら -
- や -
- ま -
- 
 -
$ odx output
0x0000: 2D 20 E3 82 93 20 2D 0A 2D 20 E3 82 8F 20 2D 0A   - ... -.- ... -.
0x0010: 2D 20 E3 82 89 20 2D 0A 2D 20 E3 82 84 20 2D 0A   - ... -.- ... -.
0x0020: 2D 20 E3 81 BE 20 2D 0A 2D 20 0A 20 2D 0A         - ... -.- . -.
0x002E:
$
```

Testing on Mac OS X 10.11.4 with GCC (5.3.0, home-built) and Clang (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)).

Given working code, you can experiment to find which changes are crucial.  I'd also create functions to report errors with one-line calls instead of needing to write 3 or 4 lines per error. (Actually 'use' is more appropriate than 'create' — I created such a set of functions long ago, and use them continually.)

Comment: Code issue solved but I also an **UNSOLVED** issue has shown up. I've Updated the question